# How to leave resources in the jar file to not need external folders?

Tags: java, 2d-games

I am finishing my first game in Java, called SpaceWar. But to build the project requires that the resources folder (where I put my Sprites etc ...) is in the same place the jar file. I wanted to know a way to let the images inside the jar file, because it is much better because it prevents the user from deleting accidentally.

Comment: Do you use any build tool (maven/gradle/ant)? What IDE do you use? It could be achieve in different way dependent on tools you use.

Answer (score 0):

Place your images into part of your java packages . For example, com.project.images

and then you may need use the following in your code  :

```
getClass().getResource("com/project/images/picture.bmp"));
```

to access the images.

then you images will be part of the jar.